# Computing integral of distribution function

Tags: integration, probability-theory

Let $F$ be a distribution function. Compute

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(x+10)-F(x)\mathop{dx}$$

I tried to do this using the definition of the cdf. I wrote it out and took complements but then I just got a bunch of double integrals. I'm pretty sure you need to use Fubinis theorem (not 100% sure though) to solve this problem but I really cannot figute this out. I am greatful for anyone's assistance

Comment: If $F$ denores CDF, then you may use $$F(x+10)-F(x)=\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{\{X-10\leq x<X\}}]$$ and Fubini's theorem. The answer is then 10.

Comment: How do you do Fubinis theorem on that?

Comment: We get $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}(F(x+10)-F(x))\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{\{X-10\leq x<X\}}]\,\mathrm{d}x=\mathbb{E}\left[\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbf{1}_{\{X-10\leq x<X\}}\,\mathrm{d}x\right]=\mathbb{E}[10]=10.$$

Comment: Thanks. Out of curiosity where did you use Fubini?

Comment: Expectation is simply an abstract kind of integral (integral with respect to the underlying probability measure $\mathbb{P}$), and so, interchanging the order of integral and expectation is subject to Fubini's theorem. This abstraction can be partially circumvented by invoking Riemann-Stieltjes integral as in Kavi's answer, but the necessity of Fubini-Tonelli theorem persists.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int [F(x+10)-F(x)] dx=\int \int_{(x,x+10]}dF(y)dx$$ $$=\int \int_{y-10}^{y} dx dF(y)=\int 10 dF(y)=10$$.

Interchange of order of integration is justified by Tonelli's Theorem.